# How to access the struct attribute inside a struct by reference

Tags: c++

I have the following structures with me.

```
typedef struct _abc{
    int x;
    int y;
} abc;

typedef struct _def{
    abc a;
    int b;
} def;
```

I want to read the `abc` structure which is inside `def`. I do it in the following way.

```
int main() {
    def x;
    x.a = abc();  // Initializing 'a'
    std::cout << &x.a << std::endl;
    abc y = x.a;  // Accessing 'a' later
    std::cout << &y << std::endl;
}
```

But from the console output I realized that the object reference is changed. That means the structure attribute is copied. 
In the real-world scenario, `structure abc` is large and making copies every time I access it will take a lot of time.

```
typedef struct _def{
    _def(abc &_a){b=0;a=_a;}
    abc &a;
    int b;
} def;


int main() {
    abc a;
    def x(a);
    std::cout << &x.a << std::endl;
    abc y = x.a;
    std::cout << &y << std::endl;
}
```

I tried this way also, but it gives me compile error.

Is there a way to access members of a class without copying them..?

Comment: You seriously need to read a beginner C++ book, as the code you have written here is a weird mix of C and C++ and you lack understanding of the basics of the object model.

Comment: In C++ you don't have to write `typedef struct _x {} x;`. It was a hack in C but in C++ you don't need it. You can just write: `struct x {};`

Comment: "But from the console output I realized that the object reference is changed" what reference changed? The question would be more clear if you spelled out what you expect to get from that code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a way: ***references***.

First, let's transform your program from C into C++ (your version is syntactically valid but represents an antiquated form of the art; we'll also add a missing header):

```
#include <iostream>

struct abc
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct def
{
    abc a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    def x;

    // No need for this at all; creating `x` already created `x.a`
    // x.a = abc();

    // Prints the address of `x.a`
    std::cout << &x.a << std::endl;


    abc y = x.a;

    // Prints the address of the _copy_ of `x.a` that you just made,
    // called `y`
    std::cout << &y << std::endl;


    abc& z = x.a;

    // Prints the address of the `x.a` via a reference called `z`
    std::cout << &z << std::endl;
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f732005108dd587))

As you can see from the above code, and from the demo, it is possible to declare a *reference* that acts as a new name for an existing object.

Please turn to the page in your introductory C++ book about references; they should be well explained therein.

Answer (score 4):

You can use reference. Change

```
abc y = x.a;  // Accessing 'a' later
```

to:

```
abc &y = x.a;  // Accessing 'a' later
```

Then there is no copy.

Answer (score 4):

You can directly access a structure inside a structure without building any additional construct for that.

To fix the compilation error, you have to initialize the reference via [Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

```
typedef struct _def{
    _def(abc &_a): a{_a} // a{_a} is the initializer list
    {
        b=0;
    }

    abc &a;
    int b;
} def;
```

Or in case you need a shorthand for the member, you can create a reference to the member directly:

```
abc &y = x.a;
```